# Querying database when using viewmodel on web application asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, viewmodel

I have a problem with viewmodel, when I try to add new enregistrement to my database when I have view titly typed with my viewmodel I get `DbEntityValidationErrors`.

This is code using viewmodel :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Annonce annonce)
    {
        /*
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          */  

            _userservice.addannonce(annonce);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        /*
        }

       return View(new AnnonceView(annonce));
         * */
    }
```

But when I use my entity domain Annonce directly on view, there is any problem. Help me please and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuimng your addannounce method is expecting an object of your EntityModel type. Not Viewmodel. ViewModel is specific to handle the View. It is not same as your Entity Model. You can not send a View Model which you created as it is to the entity framework to save it. You need to send an Entity Model. So probably you can read the values of ViewModel and set as the relevant property values of Entity Model and send that to be saved. Something like this

```
YoueEntity.Announce objEntityAnnounce=new YoueEntity.Announce();
//Read from the posted viewmodel and set the values to entity model.
objEntityAnnounce.ID=annonce.ID;
objEntityAnnounce.Title=annonce.Title;
//Other relevant Properties as well

_userservice.addannonce(objEntityAnnounce);
```

There are libraries like AutoMapper which does this mapping, You may take a look at them,

Comment: thanks Mr Shyju , i understand your point , but i don't want to use automapper, ihaven't time to leran it , this is my view model

Comment: @ucef: Then you may manually map like the way i didn in my answer.

Comment: thanks Mr Shyju i have mistake on method `create (Annonceview annonceview)`but the method addannonce take a parametre annonce which is my entities, and i dont have time to learn about automapper. Best Regards